# Django restrict views by User permissions which are editable in the Admin

Tags: django

I have a Django application where I need to restrict specific `Views` to subset of `Users`. I also want to be bale to edit which `Users` have this permission via the Django Admin. So in the admin I would like to be able to see all users and have a check box which can be checked to give permission to see this specific `Views`.

I believe the way to approach to this is to a permissions decorator on the `Views` in question:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required

@login_required
@permission_required('user.can_view_restricted', login_url='/accounts/login/')
def Restrictedview(request, template_name='restricted.html'):
    ...
    # restricted stuff
```

Now I know I need to define this permission (in permissions.py?), and register it with the Admin. I am unsure of how to do this and how to properly associate the permission with a specific `User` instance. Should this be an extra field on 'User', or a separate model to hold model to hole Users and Permissions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read in details about django permissions in the docs
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization

Basically Django permissions use the `Permission` model, which is found at `django.contrib.auth.models`, but for most applications you don't need to directly import or use that model.

By default Django creates 3 default permissions for any model you have in your app. If you have a model named `MyModel` in an app named `myapp`, then Django will create `create_mymodel`, `change_mymodel`, and `delete_mymodel` permissions by default.

You can check if the user has a certain permission by calling

```
user.has_perm('myapp.create_mymodel')
```

if you're checking for the `create` permission for example. Or, like you did, you can use the decorator

```
permission_required('myapp.create_mymodel')
```

In addition to the default permissions provided by django, you can define custom permissions on your models by specifying the `permissions` attribute in the `Meta` class of your model like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    [...]
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("can_deliver_pizzas", "Can deliver pizzas"),
        )
```

More on defining custom permissions here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#permissions

By default, permissions can be easily edited for every user using the admin interface. Just visit a certain user's page and there will be a field named User Permissions with a list of all permissions in your project, from which you can add or remove permissions for your particular user.

Comment: Yeah - I just discovered that you can add `from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission; admin.site.register(Permission)` to `admin.py` and do the rest via the admin. Crazy simple!